# Powershell Select-Object Formatting

Tags: powershell

```
$output = $data | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$serverName"} | Select-Object -Property Description1,Version | Where-Object {$_.Description1 -eq "Power controller Firmware"} | Select-Object -Property Version  

Write-Host $output
```

Gives me the following output:

```
    @{Version=3.4}
```

So $data is an array and I select what I want form it and assign it to a variable to eventually be inputted into a excel file but no matter what I seem to try I cant just select "3.4" Instead it selects like the above (@{Version=3.4}). Doesn't anybody know how to just select the "3.4" within my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace last line with:

```
foreach( $out in $output )
{
Write-Host $out.Version
}
```

In fact your $output variable contains an array so you need to go through it with a foreach loop.
Then you can `Write-Host` or do anything with the Version property.

As stated by @okaram, if you want to make the same kind of looping but after a pipe you can do it this way:

```
$output | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Version}
```

or

```
$output | %{Write-Host $_.Version}
```

Comment: Cool, I was going to suggest printing it, so glad to see somebody else agrees. Hoping to see something better :)

Comment: BTW, since the syntax was with |, you can also do something like %{"{0}" -f $_.Version} at the end.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot man! Is that usually how you do it? Or is there another way when your searching to just grab that right away? Thanks though, I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Yes it is usually done this way. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your last expression of

```
Select-Object -Property Version
```

Keeps the entire object in the pipeline, but filters down the properties to only Version.  However, the -ExpandProperty will put the property value itself in the pipeline.

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
```

That should return the "3.4" result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
$data | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$serverName"} | Select-Object -Property 
Description1, Version | Where-Object {$_.Description1 -eq "Power controller
Firmware"} | write-Host $_.Version
```